# How can I check if the user input is a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to check if the user inputs a string. If the user inputs a string, my program should output an error message. If the user enters an integer my program should proceed with the program

Here's my code so far, I need to add another condition to check if the user inputs string, I tried some methods but they don't work

```
public int UserInput() {
    boolean Continueasking = true;
    int Input = 0;
    while (Continueasking) {
        Input = io.nextInt();
        if (Input == 1 || Input==2 || Input==3) {
            Continueasking = !Continueasking;
        } else {
            System.out.println("try again");
        }
    }
    return Input;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextInt()` parses user input as an integer. If the user input can't be parsed as an integer, it throws `InputMismatchException`. You can catch this exception and handle it as you see fit.

```
while (continueAsking) {
    try {
       input = io.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
       // invalid input - handle exception
    }
}
```